# onClick() method crashes

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my project. When I click the `Search` button, my application will crash on my phone. the "Search" button is a method where it retrieves information from `SQLiteDatabase`. This activity is Where Clause activity. Whenever I click the Search button, it crashes.

This is my coding:

```
package com.example.taza.rshinventorymanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView locationoutput, quantityoutput, size1output, size2output, size3output,
            size4output, size5output, size6output, size7output, size8output, size9output,
            size10output, size11output, size12output, size13output, sizeXSoutput, sizeSoutput,
            sizeMoutput, sizeLoutput, sizeXLoutput, size2XLoutput;

    EditText searchproduct;

    ProductDBHelper productDBHelper;

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    String Searchproduct;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        Button LoginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.HomepageLoginButton);
        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginPage.class);

                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
        });

        searchproduct = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.HomepageET);

        locationoutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HPLocation);
        quantityoutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HPQuantity);
        size1output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP1);
        size2output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP2);
        size3output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP3);
        size4output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP4);
        size5output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP5);
        size6output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP6);
        size7output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP7);
        size8output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP8);
        size9output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP9);
        size10output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP10);
        size11output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP11);
        size12output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP12);
        size13output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP13);
        sizeXSoutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HPXS);
        sizeSoutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HPS);
        sizeMoutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HPM);
        sizeLoutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HPL);
        sizeXLoutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HPXL);
        size2XLoutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HP2XL);

        locationoutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        quantityoutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size1output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size1output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size2output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size3output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size4output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size5output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size6output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size7output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size8output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size9output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size10output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size11output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size12output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size13output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sizeXSoutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sizeSoutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sizeMoutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sizeLoutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sizeXLoutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        size2XLoutput.setVisibility(View.GONE);




    }

    public void SearchProduct (View view)
    {
        Searchproduct = searchproduct.getText().toString();
        productDBHelper = new ProductDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = productDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = productDBHelper.getProduct(Searchproduct, sqLiteDatabase);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            String locationsearch = cursor.getString(0);
            String quantitysearch = cursor.getString(1);
            String size1search = cursor.getString(2);
            String size2search = cursor.getString(3);
            String size3search = cursor.getString(4);
            String size4search = cursor.getString(5);
            String size5search = cursor.getString(6);
            String size6search = cursor.getString(7);
            String size7search = cursor.getString(8);
            String size8search = cursor.getString(9);
            String size9search = cursor.getString(10);
            String size10search = cursor.getString(11);
            String size11search = cursor.getString(12);
            String size12search = cursor.getString(13);
            String size13search = cursor.getString(14);
            String sizeXSsearch = cursor.getString(15);
            String sizeSsearch = cursor.getString(16);
            String sizeMsearch = cursor.getString(17);
            String sizeLsearch = cursor.getString(18);
            String sizeXLsearch = cursor.getString(19);
            String size2XLsearch = cursor.getString(20);

            locationoutput.setText(locationsearch);
            quantityoutput.setText(quantitysearch);
            size1output.setText(size1search);
            size2output.setText(size2search);
            size3output.setText(size3search);
            size4output.setText(size4search);
            size5output.setText(size5search);
            size6output.setText(size6search);
            size7output.setText(size7search);
            size8output.setText(size8search);
            size9output.setText(size9search);
            size10output.setText(size10search);
            size11output.setText(size11search);
            size12output.setText(size12search);
            size13output.setText(size13search);
            sizeXSoutput.setText(sizeXSsearch);
            sizeSoutput.setText(sizeSsearch);
            sizeMoutput.setText(sizeMsearch);
            sizeLoutput.setText(sizeLsearch);
            sizeXLoutput.setText(sizeXLsearch);
            size2XLoutput.setText(size2XLsearch);

            locationoutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            quantityoutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size1output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size1output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size2output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size3output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size4output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size5output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size6output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size7output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size8output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size9output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size10output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size11output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size12output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size13output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sizeXSoutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sizeSoutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sizeMoutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sizeLoutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sizeXLoutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            size2XLoutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
}
```

I found the Logcat after i debug. Here's the error:

```
01-24 12:07:21.692 3720-3720/? E/DATABASE OPERATIONS: Database created / opened...
01-24 12:07:21.695 3720-3720/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEproduct_information": syntax error
01-24 12:07:21.695 3720-3720/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-24 12:07:21.696 3720-3720/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.taza.rshinventorymanager, PID: 3720
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEproduct_information": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEproduct_information(product_codeTEXT,product_locationTEXT,product_quantityTEXT,size_1TEXT,size_2TEXT,size_3TEXT,size_4TEXT,size_5TEXT,size_6TEXT,size_7TEXT,size_8TEXT,size_9TEXT,size_10TEXT,size_11TEXT,size_12TEXT,size_13TEXT,size_XSTEXT,size_STEXT,size_MTEXT,size_LTEXT,size_XLTEXT,size_2XLTEXT)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                     at com.example.taza.rshinventorymanager.ProductDBHelper.onCreate(ProductDBHelper.java:52)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                     at com.example.taza.rshinventorymanager.Homepage.SearchProduct(Homepage.java:101)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: It crashed? So whats the crash about ? Add the complete stacktrace too .

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: @ADM The application can run on my phone, but whenever i click the "Search" button, it just crash. the application exits

Comment: @ArslanAli i didn't run the application on AVD, since my AVD can't detect my project. i just run on my phone

Comment: i hope you guys can help me. i seriously don't know what to do.

Comment: even if you run it on phone you still get the logcat for it. WIthout logcat it is difficult to judge what went wrong

Comment: @MurtazaAdhaMohamad where is the search button initialization and listener ?

Comment: @ArslanAli i open my Logcat, and it is empty

Comment: @Joe but onClick method doesn't need to declare listener right?

Comment: Yeah.But where is the onclick method. You didn't post it.

Comment: @Joe the public void SearchProduct (View view) is my onClick method

Comment: @ArslanAli android studio doesn't detect any error in my coding. and i whenever i run my project using AVD, AVD can't detect my project. so the only way is to install straight to my phone. so i don't know the error

Comment: @ArslanAli i already post my logcat. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are writing **onClick** method inside **onCreate**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginPage.class);
startActivity(startIntent);
}
```

Comment: So where exactly should i put it?

Comment: Outside of onCreate Function,

Comment: and replace LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()) to LoginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: I don't think, setting listener is a problem. Even inside , it will work.

Comment: i already post my logcat